# vb.net how to handle text dragged onto a button to open a new form with the dragged text directly copied to the richtextbox on the new form?

Tags: vb.net, text, drag-and-drop

I want to achieve the following:

The user drags text from any open window not related to my application ( like firefox or word, for example) onto button1 on form1 in my application. when he/she does that, a new form (called form2 that contains a richtextbox) will open and the dragged text is directly copied (or inserted) into the richtextbox of the new form. button1 has allowdrop set to true. Beyond that I don't know how to proceed.

I tried:

```
e.effects = DragDropEffects.Copy
```

But it seems it is not enough. Could you help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm sharing so others might benefit.

First, I declared a global variable in one of the modules:

```
Public draggedText As String = ""
```

Second, I handled the dragdrop event on the button as follows:

```
Private Sub button1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles button1.DragDrop
    draggedText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)
    frm_form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Third, in the load event of frm_form2 I added the following:

```
If draggedText <> "" Then
        richTextBox1.Text = draggedText
        draggedText = ""
End If
```

That's it. Not as complicated as I thought. Also, you can add the code for the dragEnter event mentioned in the previous answer to change how the cursor looks.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Learning about Drag and Drop would be the first step. http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_drag_drop.html -or- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289508%28VS.71%29.aspx.

Essentially, you need to enable the drag and drop for the target, handle the drag and drop events, and then implement your desired action.

From MSDN regarding Dragging Text:

```
Private MouseIsDown As Boolean = False
```

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    ' Set a flag to show that the mouse is down.
    MouseIsDown = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseMove
    If MouseIsDown Then
        ' Initiate dragging.
        TextBox1.DoDragDrop(TextBox1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End If
    MouseIsDown = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.DragEnter
    ' Check the format of the data being dropped.
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
        ' Display the copy cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        ' Display the no-drop cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.DragDrop
    ' Paste the text.
    TextBox2.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)
End Sub

Comment: thanks for your response. I am aware of the above mentioned method and already read the articles you posted. However, this does not help me. the code you wrote and the articles you posted assume you want to drag-drop from one control on your form to another. What I want is different (as described in my original question). But thanks, anyway, for your help.